# Scroll Grid-view when TreeView Item is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scroll, treeview

In my webpage I have a TreeView and a GridView.

Grid-view contains Items which are categorized into some Category Names. The category names are placed in Tree-view.

[image]

When we click on a Category name in Tree-view The page should scroll to the particular Category in Grid-view. In the above Image the left side one is the Tree-view and the right side one is the Grid-view. The blocks in the Grid-view are the Categorical order of Items.

I need to scroll the page to particular category when the Category in the Grid-view is clicked!

Can you help me in doing this??

Comment: I have approximately the same question!